# Showing Shannon's formula

Tags: logarithms, entropy

Well, I'm having this in a textbook [1] :

\begin{align*}
H(U_N) &= H_1 + H_2 \\
\log_2 N &= H_1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{N_k}{N} \log_2 N_k \\
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{N_k}{N}\log_2 N &= H_1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{N_k}{N} \log_2 N_k \\
\Rightarrow H_1 &= - \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{N_k}{N} \log_2 \frac{N_k}{N} 
\end{align*}

Which is supposed to show Shannon's formula.

However, I just don't get the step from line 1 to line 2. I tried to get there myself but it actually looks kind of wrong. I don't want to disgrace myself here but how does this make sense? Also notice the upper limit of the sum changing from $n$ to $N$ which is also rather weird. $n$ should be the number of groups, if I got that right and $N$ should be the number oh how many different numbers one can represent in base 2 using a certain number of bits as in:

How many times do I have to ask at most to guess a binary digit?

\begin{align*}
n &= \log_2 2^n = \log_2 N
\end{align*}

so we have

\begin{align*}
H(U_N) = \log_2 N \text{ bit}
\end{align*}

to store a corresponding message.

Also we're demanding that

\begin{align*}
H(U_{N \cdot M}) = H(U_N) + H(U_M)
\end{align*}

---

The only possibility for

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{N_k}{N} \log_2 N &= \log_2 N
\end{align*}

is if

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^n N_k &= 1
\end{align*}

but would only work if we actually have something like

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{k=1}^n w_k N &= 1 \Rightarrow \sum_{k=1}^n w_k = 1
\end{align*}

or

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n N_k  &= N 
\end{align*}

But from what I saw I expected each $N_k$ to be $2^\text{something}$.

---

[1] *Elements of Information Theory, Thomas M. Cover, Joy A. Thomas*

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: @r.e.s. It's just a summary written by a tutor actually.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=Bn2gjlsoi2UC&printsec=frontcover&dq=mathematical+foundation+of+information+theory+khinchin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM0cHE04rQAhVI1oMKHex-CBQQ6AEIIDAA#v=onepage&q=shannon&f=false

Comment: @avs Is there a specific page I should look at or is this an ad?

Comment: I think it's being assumed that $N=N_1+...+N_n$. The $N$ as a summation limit is surely a typo that should be $n$. The second line then follows from the first, and so on, assuming the usual additive properties of the entropy function: Consider that a uniform distribution on $N$ items can be generated in two steps, using a partition into $n$ disjoint groups: first choose one of the $n$ groups (with probabilities $p_k=\frac{N_k}{N}$), then choose an item uniformly from that group.

Comment: @r.e.s. Yes, I think I found my issue here. I somehow thought that e.g. if $N = 2^9$ and I can "*group however I like*" the $N_k$ can be e.g. $N_1 = 2^6, N_2 = 2^3$ and then I have $N = N_1 * N_2 = 2^6 * 2^3$. Having $\sum_{k=1}^n N_k = N$ changes things of course. I think I get it now - the only thing I don't understand from here is actually *why* the groups don't have to be the same size.

Comment: Oh, I think I just realized why the groups don't have to be the same size ^^

Comment: @displayname not an ad.  Go by the table of contents.

Comment: @r.e.s. I posted an answer but I'm not 100% certain if I got that correct - would you mind taking a look at it? ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I get it now. We have $\log_2(2^n) = \log_2(N) = n$ as the answer to the question

> "*How many times do I have to ask to identify a number written in base 2 in a set of $N = 2^n$ different numbers?*"

We define Hartley's function $H(U_N)$ where $U_N$ is a set with $N$ different elements with equal probability. Thus, the required amount of information to identify an element in $U_N$ is

\begin{align*}
H(U_N) &= \log_2 N \text{ bit}
\end{align*}

We also require

\begin{align*}
\text{1.  }&H(U_2) = 1 \\
\text{2.  }&H(U_N) \leq H(U_{N+1}) \\
\text{3.  }&H(U_{N\cdot M}) = H(U_N) + H(U_M)
\end{align*}

**Example:**

If we want to know an element in $N = 2^3$ different elements, we can e.g. group them in $G_1 = \{000,001,010,011\}$ and $G_2 = \{100,101,110,111\}$ (Note that $N = |G_1| + |G_2| = N_1 + N_2)$. We already see, that we need 3 bits to encode all these elements. If we decide e.g. the first bit as identifier for one of the two groups we have:

```
Group 1 | Group 2
-----------------
  000   |   100
  001   |   101
  010   |   110
  011   |   111
```

and we can calculate this with

\begin{align*}
H(U_{2 \cdot 4}) &= H(U_{2}) + H(U_{4}) \\
&= \log_2(2) + \log_2(4) \\
&= 3
\end{align*}

Now we want to know the following: If we take such a $H(U_N)$ that we group in the described manner as above we can "split" the question "*Which element in the set $G_1 \cup G_2$ are you?*" by asking the question $H_1$ ("*in which group do you belong?*") and $H_2$ ("*Knowing the group, which element in that group are you?*").

\begin{align*}
H(U_N) = H_1 + H_2
\end{align*}

For $H_2$ we know that we need $\log_2 N_k$ questions to identify an object in the group. The average number of questions with respect to a group depends on the size of the group and thus we have

\begin{align*}
H_2 &= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{N_k}{N} \log_2 N_k
\end{align*}

What's now missing is $H_1$. We want to know the missing part of information to calculate $H(U_N)$ or in other words: Not knowing $H_1$, how much information would I *gain* if I knew it?

\begin{align*}
H(U_N) &= H_1 + H_2 \\
\log_2 N &= H_1 + H_2 \\
\log_2 N  &= H_1 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{N_k}{N} \log_2 N_k \\
\Rightarrow H_1 &= \log_2 N - \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{N_k}{N} \log_2 N_k \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{N_k}{N} \log_2 N - \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{N_k}{N} \log_2 N_k & \text{Because: } \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{N_k}{N} = 1 \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{N_k}{N} \Big( \log_2 N -  \log_2 N_k \Big) \\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{N_k}{N} \Big( \log_2 N_k -  \log_2 N \Big) \\
&= -\sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{N_k}{N} \log_2 \frac{N_k}{N}
\end{align*}

We now know that

\begin{align*}
H_1 &= - \sum_{k=1}^n p_k \log_2 p_k
\end{align*}

where $p_k = \frac{N_k}{N}$ which is the amount of information we would gain if we knew in which group our element falls into.

---

The reason why I didn't get it was actually just because I didn't see that $\sum_{k=1}^n N_k = N$.

Comment: :)  looks good to me briefly very briefly skimming over it (though I must admit, it was *very* brief, not a lot of time today!). Good job!

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks :) I'll mark it as accepted. If there's a mistake people will notify or edit :)